# Showing there doesnt exists a continuous function which satisfies all the below conditions

Tags: calculus

Let $0 \leq$ a $\leq 1$; prove that there does not exist a continuous function $f:[0,1] \rightarrow(0, \infty)$ which satisfy all the following conditions :
\begin{align}\int_{0}^{1} f(x) d x &= 1 ,\\ 
\int_{0}^{1} x f(x) d x& = a,\\
\int_{0}^{1} x^{2} f(x) d x&=a^{2}.
\end{align}
My work : by multiplying the second integral by $2$ and then subtracting it with the other two we get integral $(x-1)^2f(x) = (a-1)^2$ now I don't get how to show $f(x)$ doesn't exist of such type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of $\int (x-1)^{2} f(x)dx$ look at $\int (x-a)^{2} f(x)dx$.

$\int (x-a)^{2}f(x)dx=a^{2}-2(a) (a)+a^{2}=0$. Since $(x-a)^{2}f(x)$ is a non-negative continuous function it follows that $(x-a)^{2}f(x)=0$ for all $x$. Can you finish?

Comment: Well techincally still not able to prove there doenst exist any funcntion which may not satisfy that integral

Comment: @WizardMath I just added one more step.

Comment: Oh got it now Sir , if the range of f(x) is modifed that it may contain negative values too , then also will it be possible to prove the same thing of non - existing feature ?

Comment: Otherwise any counterexample for that one

Comment: @WizardMath No. If you drop non-negativity then there are infinitely many continuous functions $f$ satisfying these conditions.

Comment: Any example ? Sir

Comment: @WizardMath There is a  third degree polynomial satisfying those conditions. Use the equations to determine the coefficients of the polynomial.

Comment: I see thanks Sir got it

Comment: You may see my other math problem too Sir? Its also calculus based